# How does Sleep Works in PHP for simultaneous requests from the same user[machine]?

Tags: php, session

I was trying to understand the way sleep works for the multiple request from the same machine.

For example, I want to track the user login and logout in one of my application and I have done as explained below:

An ajax request is sent to browser when an user tries close/refresh the current browser. What I have done is binded an event on page unload, which sends an ajax request on server, where I have set up the session timestamp value in session and used the sleep(10) as below ->

```
    //sets the timestamp value
    $session->timestamp = time();

    //wait if another request arrives withing 10 seconds
    sleep(10);

    if ($session->timestamp) {

        //clear user session here
        $session->timestamp = null;
    }
```

Since I only want to reset the session only when user is trying to close his browser tab/window, it works fine in this case and reset the session after 10 seconds.

But, I do not want to reset the session in case of page refresh. Since in the case of page refresh, Again the page unload event is called first which sets the timestamp value in session, but the request is being for refresh and it sets the timestamp value at very first place as in below code:

```
    if ($session->timestamp) {
        $session->timestamp = null;
    }
```

Now what I am thinking is when 10 seconds complete in sleep call of previous request the timestamp value is set to null and therefore the user session should not be reset.

But somehow this is not the case. Might be I am missing something here.

Comment: I'm very confused. It seems like you're trying to reinvent garbage collection for sessions. There is enough literature on the subject.

Comment: Actually I need to track the login/logout activity of an user on my application. But when user directly closes the session there is no track that either is logged out or not.

Comment: For this I have added an event "onunload" which is sent on server and sets up a value "timestamp" and make the process to sleep for "10 sec" and returns nothing. But since when user is just refreshing  the page it resets the timestamp value from the session. and therefore what I was thinking that when the previous request is awake [after 10 sec] it will not get the value of timestamp and should not clear the user session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy user session after he closes browser, just set cookie without expiring date.

Comment: but I also want to log the logged out event in my database.

Comment: You can check with cron task which user was logged in for > x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You've only explained your problem in the comments - not in the question. Each http request is handled in isolation regardless if they are from the same machine, however when a client emits an http request, it may re-use an existing connection in which case the request will be blocked until the earlier request on the same socket is processed.

> I need to track the login/logout activity of an user on my application

The right way to do this is *in* the session handler (and not embedding time information inside the session itself) or via SSO. You can set a very short TTL and use a javascript invoked beacon to get better granularity of the end-of-session time in the absence of an explicit logout.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that in PHP+Javascript or provide the references for the solution you are providing?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the user specifically logs out there wont be a logout event. Because of the way websites work you can't force the user to logout. Usually sessions just time out (30 minutes is a pretty common value). If a timely logout is imporant to you consider switching it around and implement a keep-alive ticker that will periodically (every 5 minutes?) send the server a message that the user is still logged in (= has the website open in a tab).

In the session table keep a timestamp of last notify, if that timestamp is too old you can consider the user has logged out. Run a scheduled job to record the log out 'event'.

Using `onunload` to perform an AJAX request is very unreliable because you can not force the browser to wait and you can not distguinish between a reload/redirect or a close.